# What is the difference between Obsculta and Exaudi?

Tags: vocabulary

In the Rule of St Benedict we find:

**Obsculta, o fili, præcepta magistri,**

https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/benedict.html

We also have this in some prayers: **Exaudī nos Domine sancte, Pater omnipotens, aeterne Deus...**

What is the difference between Obsculta and Exaudi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to get this out of the way, *obscultare* is a variant of *auscultare*, which is the form you will find in most dictionaries. *Exaudire*, on the other hand, is a member of the *audire* family of words.

The difference, roughly speaking, is that *auscultare* means to listen attentively, believingly, or even obediently. It tends to imply a certain effort on part of the listener; it is also used for eavesdroppers and servants waiting on someone. Here is what Forcellini [has to say](http://lexica.linguax.com/forc2.php?searchedLG=ausculto):

> Saepe plus est quam *audire*: significat enim non solum auribus accipere, sed etiam fidem habere dictis alicujus, eique aliquid praecipienti aut monenti obtemperare, obsequi

*Exaudire* – which differs from simple *audire*, insofar as it does differ from it at all, in that it means “to hear from afar, to hear loud and clear” – does not have such connotations. Like English “hear,” it can mean to heed, to grant (in particular *vota* and *preces*, which already in classical Latin belies a certain religious tendency). Indeed, it can even mean to obey, although that's somewhat unusual.

Thus, in English terms you could translate St. Benedict as saying: “Listen closely, son, to the teacher's directions …” – this is clearly not how you address God in a prayer. *Exaudi nos, Domine* &c., on the other hand, could be translated as "hear us, Lord" (in English, “hear our prayers” would be more idiomatic; *exaudi preces nostras* would certainly not sound wrong in Latin either).